# Navigating using RGBDSLAM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone used RGBDSLAM for navigation and/or obstacle avoidance? If yes, are there any available packages? I was thinking of combining RGBDSLAM with the explore package, but I might not have enough experience yet to program it myself.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63610/navigating-using-rgbdslam/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-05-27**:
What kind of camera are you using for RGBD slam??

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-27**:
Asus Xtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure whether a specific package exist for exploring using RGBD slam. If exploring is ur final aim then u can use pointcloud_to_laserscan package and then, those laserscan can be used to create 2d map which can be used for exploration. Checkout turtlebot navigation packages. It covers lot of details but instead of a stereo camera, it uses Kinect.

Hope this helps...

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-27**:
Thanks, I will look into that. However, that means that the robot could bump into higher objects that can't be detected on a 2D floor map.

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-05-27**:
If there are some objects hanging in the air, then it might happen ...

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-28**:
My robot is about 1m high (it has an arm, etc), so it could bump into a table with legs or something of the sort. That's why I wanted to use 3D nav & obstacle avoidance. I guess I could extract a few 2D maps at different z coordinates.

**Comment by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on 2013-08-12**:
So did you make any progress with this? Actually, I am working on a similar project and would really appreciate it if you could help me out.
Thanks..

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-08-13**:
Unfortunately, I haven't. I realized that my robot's computer lacks GPU resources to use RGBDSLAM for such a task... The program becomes too slow after mapping a small room. Hence, I'm just using the standard explore package.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-08-13**:
Maybe this would help you if you're interested in explore: http://answers.ros.org/question/64461/fuerte-explore-package-in-a-real-environment-problem-again/

**Comment by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on 2013-08-13**:
I'll look into the modified explore package you developed...Thanks